# Nothing is being drawn to canvas for my onclick star effect in Javascript for canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, drawing

When the user clicks on the canvas the e.eventY and e.eventX are saved as clickX and clickY.

Passed as parameters to drawStarCracks(clickX, clickY).

Availangles is a portmanteau for available angles: newAvailangles is a list with value [0 ... 360].

A randomly chosen angle and length draw a line and remove 10 availangles to either side.

This continues till centerAvailangles.length == 0.

I've console logged and the math adds up inside the drawing function, but nothing shows on screen.

CSS for the canvas to fill the screen. I doubt its the issue but who knows?

```
> /* glass breaking minigame */
> #frosted-glass {
>     content: "";
>     position: absolute;
>     display: block;
>     top: 0;
>     left: 0;
>     width: 100%;
>     height: 300%;
>     overflow: auto;
>     background-color: rgba(214, 214, 214, 0.5);
>     z-index: 1;
>     -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
>     backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
>     box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000;
>     cursor: url(../png/hammer-cursor.png), crosshair; }
> 
> #frosted-glass:active {
>     cursor: url(../png/hammer-click.png), crosshair; }
```

I made a wrapper for drawing the line that uses angles and length and helper functions

```
makeLine = (x, y, angle, length) => {
    const { x2, y2 } = calcX2Y2(x, y, angle, length);
    
    console.log("Drawing line from", x, y, "to", x2, y2);
    
    context.moveTo(x, y);
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineTo( x2, y2 );
    context.stroke();
    
}
// Pick from a list.
function pickFrom(list) {
    return list[Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length)];
}

// Splice 10 to either side of angle if still there.
removeChunkFromAvailangles = (availangles, angle) => {
    for (i = -10; i <= 10; i++) {
        availangles.splice(availangles.indexOf(angle + i), 1);
    }
};

calcX2Y2 = (x, y, angle, length) => {
    return {
        x2: x + Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * length,
        y2: y + Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * length
    };
}
```

And now the star of the show

```
// Lines from center out to the edge of the circle.
// Completely exhausts the availangles list for the center point.
function drawStarCracks(clickX, clickY) {
    
    console.log("Drawing star cracks...");
    
    const centerAvailangles = structuredClone(newAvailangles);
    while (centerAvailangles.length > 0) {

        console.log("availangles:", centerAvailangles);
        
        let angle = pickFrom(centerAvailangles);
        
        console.log("angle:", angle);

        removeChunkFromAvailangles(centerAvailangles, angle);

        makeLine(clickX, clickY, angle, (Math.random() * 180 + 180));

    }
}
```

A clip of what is console logged:

```
    availangles: (45) [59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309]
    pickedAngle: 72
    Drawing line from 489 190 to 586.6792253500466 490.6257437838702
    availangles: (24) [59, 60, 61, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169]
    angle: 129
    Drawing line from 489 190 to 264.85718469949705 466.79332527235243
    availangles: (3) [59, 60, 61]
    angle: 60
    Drawing line from 489 190 to 631.7652823001483 437.2767225007707
```

I've initialized the canvas with standard syntax

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("frosted-glass"),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.lineWidth = 1;
context.strokeStyle = "black";
```

If I've missed anything my code is at

https://github.com/BrianStinerGithub/Portfolio-Site/blob/master/static/js/glassSmash.js

Comment: StructuredClone is a builtIn function, and its working.  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone

Comment: In the `makeLine()` function move `context.beginPath();` before `context.moveTo(x, y);`

Comment: Woo! 
I got a star, but it fills the whole screen and the center is the opposite corner to where I clicked.
Those bugs seem really fixable though!

Comment: Congratulations! The rest should be a walk in the park. =)

Comment: I console logged the canvas height and width and they were really small, 300 x 150. 
My css sets the width to 100% and the height to 300% but I think that just stretched it.

Comment: Exactly - the canvas real size in pixel is set via it's width and height properties.